# How to express the following regex: a numerical string only contains two or three number

Tags: regex

A numerical string contains three numbers at the most.

For example: `11881818, 123123`

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea about this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
^\D*(?:\d+\D+){2}\d*\D*$
```

- `^$` - from the start til the end
- `\D*` - there might be a non-number sequence at the start or the end of the string
- `(?:\d+\D+){2}` - there are at least two digit - non-digit sequences in the string
- `\d*` - there might be a third number sequence

Answer (score 0):

^(\d)\1*(\d)*(?:\1|\2)*(\d)*(?:\1|\2|\3)*$